# angular check if item exists in scope (array) already

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to check if I have something in an array already before adding - so that I cannot add the same type more than once. I am checking the model of the drop down I am selecting from against the array I am storing everything in (there is a slight difference in that the model stores the id as id and the array as skillId).

I am basically just trying to look through the array and see if the id matches - and if it does do not add the item to the array. Here is the code.

```
$scope.saveSkill = function() {
    //send skill to get path, then add to skills array
    console.log($scope.pathArray);
    console.log($scope.scope5.id);
    var skillCheck = true;
    //check if exists aready
    for(i=0;i<$scope.pathArray.length;i++){

        if($scope.pathArray[i].skillId = $scope.scope5.id ){
            console.log("Cannot add same skill more than once");
            skillCheck = false;

        }
    }

     if(skillCheck){
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/findPathScopeToSkill/' + $scope.scope5.id + "/1"
        })
        .success(function(data){
            angular.forEach(data.paths, function(index) {
            $scope.pathArray.push(index);
        });

        });
    }
};
```

Just as a quick reference  - pathArray is where the items get pushed into and where I do not want to have doubles - so I am checking the current id vs the id's inside the array (only difference is they are .skillId's)

I can add one, then can't add the same one again BUT I also can't add any after that. Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `$scope.pathArray[i].skillId === $scope.scope5.id` it should be `===` or `==` instead of `=` its a typo. Also if you find a match just put a break to stop looping through. Marking for closure for typo!!

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe it, haha! Thank you.